# while vs if in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

How do you distinguish from a while loop vs. an if statement in x86 Assembly?
Say my program is getting this x86 Assembly:

```
  jmp    .L2               # jump to test at end
  .L4:
        movl   -4(%ebp), %eax    # eax = A
        cmpl   -12(%ebp), %eax   # compare A to C
        jge    .L3               # skip next statement if A >= C
        addl   $1, -4(%ebp)      # A++
  .L3:
        subl   $1, -8(%ebp)      # B--
  .L2:
        cmpl   $0, -8(%ebp)      # compare B to 0
        jns    .L4               # restart code if B >= 0
```

Say x is located at -8(%ebp),
At the bottom of .L2 why is this a while loop? 
 
      why is it: 
    `while(x >= 0){jump to .L4}`
 
 
     and not:
    `if(x >= 0){ jump to .L4}` ??

Comment: I don't understand your question. What makes you think that .L2 functions as a while loop? It does one compare and then either jumps or doesn't, just like an if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's a jump back in code. In other words, a jump up (pick your favorite mental model).

Meaning that the execution will reach that conditional jump again and again until the condition comes out as false. That's the definition of a `while` loop. Now, assembly does not contain a built-in notion of loops (except for the `rep` prefix, but let's not go there). Yes, it's a conditional jump - formally an `if` statement with a `goto` body. But it implements a flow control pattern of loop.

Regular `if` statements, on the other hand, are usually implemented as a conditional jump forward (down).

Comment: Incredible, thank you so much.

Comment: x86 has specific looping instructions (`LOOP`, `LOOPNE` and `LOOPE`), so I'd say it *does* have a built-in notion of loops, but they are pretty must unused these days though (for various reasons).

Comment: Also, pay attention to the `REP` prefixes. They can also act as a loop over a string or any other array.